# Android SQLite. Как вывести средние значения за сутки в течении всего периода записей?

Tags: android, sqlite

Здравствуйте, я делаю себе приложение для подтягиваний и заношу туда количество + сегодняшнюю дату, потом в график строю все это, можно ли сделать запрос в БД, что бы получать среднее значение подтягиваний за сутки каждый день? что бы я мог отслеживать общий прогресс. Как запросить просто среднее значение из выбранного диапазона я могу, а вот что бы  среднее на каждый день это вообще возможно?

Comment: Если можете запросить среднее значение из диапазона, то сделайте диапазон длительностью в 24 часа.

Comment: а как тогда из одного запроса получить средние значения за все время разбитое по 24 часа?

Comment: А, вон какое требование. Тогда уточните это в вопросе, а то непонятно.

Comment: так то можно в коде все это сделать просто запрашивая курсоры на каждый отрезок времени, я просто думал вдруг можно как то одним запросом курсора такое получить

Comment: Вопрос чисто по `sql`, в помощь http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-avg/